# grpc::grpc_cpp_plugin failed with status code 1 when installed grpc locally

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc, ros

I use `gRPC` with `ros melodic` in `ubuntu 18.04`. Since `protobuf 3.0.0` was install if I got ros-melodic-desktop-full installed, I installed grpc in a custom path.

My `CMakeLists.txt` check if `gRPC` founded, if not it will install it in project scope using `FetchContent`.

When it get `gRPC` throught `FetchContent`, every thing goes fine. But when I export these two veriables

```sh
export gRPC_DIR=~/.grpc/
export Protobuf_DIR=~/.grpc/
```

in my `.bashrc` to let CMake find my `gRPC` and `Protobuf` installed locally. It will run into error when CMake execute the custom command compile the proto files.

Error Log:

```
grpc::grpc_cpp_plugin: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

And if I replace `grpc::grpc_cpp_plugin` with the absolute path of `grpc_cpp_plugin`, which is `$HOME/.grpc/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin`, it works fine.

Here is my install script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.28.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
cd grpc
mkdir -p cmake/build
cd cmake/build
mkdir ~/.grpc
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
        -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE=CONFIG \
        -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-latomic \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/.grpc ../..
make -j$(nproc) && make install && make clean
```

Here is part of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG)

if(NOT ${gRPC_FOUND})
    include(cmake_module/FetchGRPC.cmake)
else()
    set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC protobuf::protoc)
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc::grpc_cpp_plugin)
endif()

add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${ProtoSrc}" "${GrpcSrc}" "${ProtoHds}" "${GrpcHds}"
        COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
        ARGS --grpc_out "${ProtoPath}"
        --cpp_out "${ProtoPath}"
        -I "${ProtoPath}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${ProtoFile}"
        DEPENDS "${ProtoFile}"
)
...
```

the `FetchGRPC.cmake` mention above:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    gRPC
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc
    GIT_TAG        v1.28.0
    GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
    USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE
    )
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gRPC)

if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
  find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
else ()
  set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)
endif ()

set(_REFLECTION grpc++_reflection)
set(_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE grpc++_unsecure)
set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF libprotobuf)
set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protoc>)
set(_GRPC_GRPCPP grpc++)
```

Comment: actually I can solve it with an ugly way: `set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE "$ENV{gRPC_DIR}/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin")`.

Comment: But can someone point out a more elegant way?